# What time of day is it?

Tags: time

What time of day is it?

1. It is morning.
2. It is in the morning./In the morning.
3. Morning.

Are they right? Which one is more commonly used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 3 are both correct. 2 is not.

1 is a complete, grammatically correct sentence.

3 is not a complete sentence, but in common speech and informal writing we often do not use complete sentences when the meaning is clear. This is especially true for questions. If someone asks, say, "What color shirt is Bob wearing today?", most people would answer simply "Red" (or whatever color, of course). It's not a complete sentence, but we know that you mean "Bob is wearing a red shirt today".

2 is not correct because there is nothing that is "in" the morning. If you asked, "When is the staff meeting?", then it would make sense for me to say, "The staff meeting is in the morning", or simply "In the morning." But if you ask what time of day it is, there is nothing "in" this time. It just is.

Answer (score 0):

> What time of day is it?

To respond to this question with an answer of "morning" as time of day, the complete sentence "It is morning" is proper in both written and spoken English.  In spoken English, a word is commonly used, where "Morning" would be a common response.

Use of "in the morning" in any form as a response to the question of "What time of day is it?" would be incorrect.  "In the morning" is a prepositional phrase answering the question "when" not "what".